# Having trouble with AVD on Android SDK - eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

When I start my emulator I get this error

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'device'
Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program "/home/prio/AndroidSDK/android-sdk-linux//tools/emulator": error=2, No such file or directory
```

I am running eclipse 3.8 on ubuntu 13.10 and installed sdk from android developer site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, If you are running on the 64 bit system then you need to install the library `ia32-libs` that help to 32-bit packages installed on a 64-bit installation.

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

and make sure If your system is 32 bit then you installed everything that your system support.